# XPath expression for matching MM/DD/YYYY date strings on month and year

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc, xpath-1.0

I have a table with rows that contain dates of the form `MM/DD/YYYY` such as

```
<table>
  <tr><td>02/05/2013</td></tr>
  <tr><td>03/01/2013</td></tr>
  <tr><td>04/25/2013</td></tr>
  <tr><td>05/06/2013</td></tr>
  <tr><td>06/06/2013</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have two pieces of information to work with:

- Month `MM`
- Year `YYYY`

I want to match on the appropriate row with the given `month` and `year` values. It is guaranteed that there will be at most one entry per month, so it is not important to consider the `day`. If at some point the day is required, then the expression is trivial since I will have all three pieces of information.

I am using xpath 1.0 so it does not seem like I have access to regex in my expressions. What is a reliable way to get the appropriate row, given only the month and the year? For example, if I wanted the row that corresponds to June 2013, I don't want to accidentally match on `05/06/2013`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the xpath functions and found that there was a `starts-with` function.
So a solution, assuming I am looking for June 2013, would be

`//tr[./td[starts-with(., '06') and contains(., '2013')]]`

This would avoid issues with day/month ambiguity since the dates are always `MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: Even better, `//tr[./td[starts-with(., '06/') and contains(., '/2013')]]`.

Comment: I agree, being more specific probably wouldn't hurt in this case.